# Can't insert null value into a foreign key field in MS Access

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2016

I'm using VB.NET to insert records into an MS Access table. I've run into an issue where I'm inserting a record where one of the values is blank. VB.NET throws an error because it says that a value is required for the field I'm trying to insert.

The `Sense_LanguageSource` table has six fields including the ID field:

- LanguageSourceID (Autonumber)
- SenseFK (Number)
- **LanguageCode** (Number)
- SourceWord (Short Text)
- LanguageSourceType (Short Text)
- IsWaseieigo (Yes/No)

The LanguageCode field is also a Foreign Key, which links to the `LanguageCodeValue` table, which contains a list of LanguageCodes.

This is the code I'm running to perform the insert in VB.NET:

```vb
'Finds the ID of the LanguageCode
sql = "SELECT [LanguageCodeID] FROM [LanguageCodeValue] WHERE [LanguageCode] = """ & ls.LanguageCode & """"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, myConnection)
lcodeID = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)

'Inserts the LanguageSource element
sql = "INSERT INTO [Sense_LanguageSource] ([SenseFK], [LanguageCode], [SourceWord], [LanguageSourceType], [IsWaseieigo]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, myConnection)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("[SenseFK]", senseID))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("[LanguageCode]", lcodeID))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("[SourceWord]", ls.SourceWord))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("[LanguageSourceType]", ls.LanguageSourceType))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("[IsWaseieigo]", ls.IsWaseieigo))

Try
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd.Dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

The problem is that the value I'm passing to LanguageCode is 0. My code is taking an object which may or may not contain a LanguageCode value, and running a Select query to find its ID in the `LanguageCodeValue` table. Because the particular object I'm evaluating doesn't have a LanguageCode, the first select query returns 0. When I try to pass 0 to the insert command, I get the error:

```
"You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'LanguageCodeValue'."
```

I'm not sure how to work around this. I want there to be a link between the `Sense_LanguageSource` table and the `LanguageCodeValue` table, but I don't want it to be required to insert a value for `LanguageCode`. Is it possible to insert a null value into a Foreign Key field? Or is there a way to make it not required to insert a value into this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Okay, I've worked out how to get around this problem - disable Referential Integrity on the relationship between `LanguageCodeValue` and `Sense_LanguageSource`. Probably not the best solution, but it does allow me to input 0 on the Foreign Key field.</s>

Edit: I've found a better way. Create a "Null" record on the `LanguageCodeValue` table, with blank fields, and refer to that whenever I want to indicate that there is no `LanguageCode` attached to the `Sense_LanguageSource` table.